# how to get the output at required point in android program

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

This is JSON file :

```
{
   "response":{
      "code":1,
      "message":"success"
   },
   "data":{
      "updates":[
         {
            "update_id":"67",
            "date":"6 months ago",
            "update_type":"7",
            "update_id":"67",
            "name":"ravi"
         },
         {
            "update_id":"68",
            "date":"3 months ago",
            "update_type":"5",
            "update_id":"68",
            "name":"paresh"
         },
         {
            "update_id":"69",
            "date":"1 months ago",
            "update_type":"6",
            "update_id":"69",
            "name":"sampath"
         },
         {
            "update_id":"62",
            "date":"9 months ago",
            "update_type":"6",
            "update_id":"62",
            "name":"raju"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 String str_json = "your json string from query";

    try {
        JSONObject topobj = new JSONObject(str_json);
        JSONObject innerobj = topobj.getJSONObject("yourdate");

        String name = innerobj.getString("yourdata");
        String photo = innerobj.getString("yourdata");
        JSONArray cuisines = innerobj.getJSONArray("yourdata");
        //etc etc...

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Log.e("log_tag", "result" + result.toString());
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        String data = json_data.getString("Data");
        json_data = new JSONObject(data);
        String updates = json_data.getString("updates");
        JSONArray json_data1 = new JSONArray(updates);
        for(int i = 0; i < json_data1.length(); i++) {
            json_data = json_data1.getJSONObject(i);
            String update_id = json_data.getString("update_id");
            String date = json_data.getString("date");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
```